# What is the advantage of using the Token22/token extensions program over the older SPL token program?

Tags: token-2022, token-extensions

My purpose is to mint fungible token a with a symbol and decimals.
Should I use Token22 or the the old SPL token program

- What the advantage of token-2022?
- Is it fully adopted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two separate programs right now, the original Token program and Token Extensions(token22).

The recommendation is that if you're only looking for a token to have basic transfer functionally and use Metaplex for metadata, use the original Token program.

If you want some of the extra capabilities that Token extensions give you, use Token extensions.

The extra capabilities at the time of writing are as follows:

- Custom Transfer functionality(Transfer hooks)
- Custom metadata program
- Confidential transfer
- Default Account State
- Mint Close Authority
- Immutable Owner
- Non-Transferable Tokens
- Required Memo on Transfer
- Interest-Bearing Tokens
- Permanent Delegate
- CPI Guard
- Metadata

Comment: Thanks for your great details.

Answer (score 1):

The new token program (aka Token22 aka Token Extensions) add new functionality that the older SPL token program did not have.

Each token extension can add some interesting functionality to fungible tokens created with the Token22 program:

- metadata extension - allows you to have custom metadata directly on the token mint (similar idea to using the Token Metadata program from metaplex, except you will have 1 less account and need to pay less storage rent because of that)
- non-transferable - the owner of the fungible tokens cannot send the tokens elsewhere. they can burn the tokens, closing the account. but cannot transfer them
- transfer fee - add a fee/tax on transfers of your token. specifically, you collect the fee in the token itself not another token like SOL (i.e. if TokenX has a transfer fee, then every time someone transfers or swaps TokenX, they would pay the fee in TokenX)
- required memo - every interaction with your token would require a message/[memo](https://spl.solana.com/memo) be added to it. this could be especially useful for point of sale systems and eCommerce type interactions

There are a bunch more, but these extensions seem especially interesting to me personally. You can see a list of all the [token extensions](https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#extensions) in the SPL docs. And a list of guides on [how to use many of the extensions](https://solana.com/developers/guides?tags=token+extensions) here on the solana website.

In general though, fungible tokens with this new token program are still newer and support is being rolled out throughout the ecosystem. So yes, some support is there in explorers and wallets, but not as much as the old token program (considering it has been around for multiple years, that is also understandable)

Note: At the time of me writing this, the Token22 program and most token extensions are live on mainnet and the [latest round of audits](https://spl.solana.com/token-2022#security-audits) are completed! yay!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot mint fungible token with Token2022 extension since it's still in devnet testing awaiting a full audit.

You might want to take a look at doing with a normal Metaplex function. Here's a Gist for it: https://gist.github.com/L0STE/611bf82eaef87e22a6b91eb35d1e0a44

First Part is to create the Metadata for your Fungible Token, the second part is to Mint as much token as you want with that metadata.

Comment: The Token2022 extensions are live on mainnet. However, they are only recommended for experimental use till the full audit is finished.

Comment: Thanks all for your info.

Comment: this is not true! the new token22 program is live on mainnet and has been for a bit now.
Nearly all the extensions are live, including the metadata extension. The next batch of extensions are expected to be live on mainnet soon (namely confidential transfers)

Comment: @tonton all audits were finished a few weeks ago, and the SPL docs were updated to reflect this :)